# How to set Dynamic Route by Version for ASP.NET Boilerplate Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-mvc-routing, aspnetboilerplate

I am new in boilerplate framework and i am getting issue in dynamic route for Web API

I am using controller in ASP.NET CORE 2.0 for create Web APIs. I am also using swagger-UI for API.

I want to do dynamic route for all API in controller

I try with below code

```
 [ApiVersion("1.1")]
 [ApiVersion("2.1")]
 [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
 public class TestController : AbpController
    {
        [HttpGet("", Name = "Test")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetTestId(string customerid)
        {
           ...
           // Web API Code
           ...
        }
    }
```

But its not working

**Required output route**

When using version 1.1

```
api/v1.1/Test
```

When using version 2.1

```
api/v2.1/Test
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do versioning in ASP.NET Boilerplate Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036141/how-to-do-versioning-in-asp-net-boilerplate-web-api)

Comment: No its not duplicate. It was also my own question

Comment: In my this question i can do versioning but getting issue in generate dynamic route. if i create two different controller and fix route by api/v1.1/Test  and api/v2.1/Test  then it works fine but i want to support single controller method for multiple versions and want to give dynamic route. so when i select v1.1 from swegger then API route should show api/v1.1/Test  and when i select v2.1 from swegger then API route should show api/v2.1/Test.